# Runtime "symbol lookup error" when accessing libmysqlclient.so functionality in C

Tags: mysql, c, gcc, libmysql

**Context:** I am not certain whether this is my problem or the problem of the server this is running on. I am trying to compile and run a small utility, to become a cron job, that uses the mysql libraries. The program compiles successfully with the following command, no errors or warnings:

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program -I /usr/include/mysql/ -L/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -lglib-2.0 -Wall
```

I added `-lglib-2.0` because...

**Problem:** when I then try to run the program, it aborts with the following error:

```
./my_program: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15: undefined symbol: strcpy, version GLIBC_2.0
```

The error happens at runtime, in the following line:

```
conn = mysql_init(conn);
```

`conn` is declared as `MYSQL *conn;`, this is the first time I use anything from mysql.h (except for the declarations), and `strcpy` works fine if I use it in `my_program.c` itself.

The libraries linked from `libmysqlclient.so.15` are:

```
ldd /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.15
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7ef6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7cf4000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb7cc2000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1 (0xb7ca9000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb7c84000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7c6f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7b20000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7ef7000)
```

Is there anything I can do in my code, are my compilation or linking parameters missing something, or is there a problem with the dynamic linking of the `libmysqlclient.so.15` library that lies within the library itself? If the latter (which I don't think considering that the mysql library is used in other places in the server AFAIK), what can the server's admin do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the `-rdynamic` flag to `gcc`.

Since I shouldn't flood the comment section:

`GLIBC_2.0` is a macro that is defined in `libc.so.6`. So on your system, `libc.so.6` is GNU's C library implementation.

If you are still running into problems it's very possible that `libmysqlclient.so.15` was built against a different version of `libc.so.6` and expects different symbols. In that case you may have to rebuild `libmysqlclient.so` from source to link with the libraries on the system, or see if there is an upgraded version available for your platform.

Comment: Thanks, but this results in the same error :( I realized that there certainly is a libc.so.6 in the /lib/ path, which appears to be the Linux fork, but I don't see a file that could be the GLIBC_2.0 itself - maybe that's just missing? What soname does that library commonly have?

Comment: `GLIBC_2.0` is a macro that is defined in `libc.so.6`. So on your system, `libc.so.6` is GNU's C library implementation. If you are still running into problems it's very possible that `libmysqlclient.so.15` was built against a different version of `libc.so.6` and expects different symbols.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I found the problem. It was not in fact a symbol lookup error, but a Segmentation Fault. Because I had called `mysql_init` with an uninitialized `conn` instead of `NULL` for the initialization, `libmysqlclient` must have broken down and, for reasons beyond my limited knowledge of C, produced the wrong error message.

Debugging on another system with a different build of the same OS produced the correct error, which was a lot easier to debug.